# Traffic is not being spread evenly between replicas of OpenFaas functions

Tags: kubernetes, serverless, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, openfaas

As per this [documentation](https://docs.openfaas.com/deployment/troubleshooting/#traffic-is-not-being-spread-evenly-between-functions), I have configured `direct_functions`  to false, which allows the provider to balance traffic between replicas of OpenFaas functions. But it sends the traffic to only one replica. Without using any service mesh solution how do I archive the fairly balance the traffic to all pods that are related to one openfaas function? I have deployed OpenFaas on the EKS cluster.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: where do I need to post this?